# Default gravatar picture can be wrongly selected as profile picture

Tags: bug, status-completed, gravatar, profile-picture

Hard to explain so I'll use pictures. User without Gravatar account, clicking the "change picture" link:

> [image]

Then clicking the "Gravatar" line results in:

> [image]

Upon reloading the page the profile picture is back to the default. Guess the change is failing behind the scenes, so we better be notified in such a case and have no display change.

Comment: The Gravatar URL produced by the JavaScript is double-encoded so the "use identicons" setting isn't parsed properly and it falls back to using the Gravatar logo instead (if you don't have a custom Gravatar).

Comment: So the bug is in showing that gravatar default icon?

Comment: I think so. *[3 more to go...]*

Comment: Well, bug is a bug! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed now. As usual, it was a url encoding issue (`&amp;amp;`).

Comment: Yep, now the picture is the default gravatar. Thanks! :)